# Weblogic 12c datasource disappear from the jndi tree after server reboot

Tags: jakarta-ee, jdbc, datasource, jndi, weblogic12c

This is very annoy issue for me when I every time reboot my Macmini server.

Environments:

```
Macmini server runs OSX 10.10.3
JDK 1.8.0_45
Weblogic 12c (fusion middleware version)
```

Application:

EJB 3.1 Beans (include session bean, singleton bean), it is pure EJB application without web-layer to provide business logic to serve multiple web applications.

I follow Oracle JDBC datasource process to build the jdbc datasource from administrator console. The config.xml in mydomain/config folder looks like:

```xml
<jdbc-system-resource>
    <name>JDBC Data Source-ozssc-100</name>
    <target>AdminServer</target>
    <descriptor-file-name>jdbc/JDBC_Data_Source-ozssc-100-8091-jdbc.xml</descriptor-file-name>
</jdbc-system-resource>
```

there is linked configure file for this datasource in mydomain/config/jdbc shows as:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<jdbc-data-source xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/jdbc-data-source"
    xmlns:sec="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/wls" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/jdbc-data-source 
    http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/jdbc-data-source/1.0/jdbc-data-source.xsd">
    <name>JDBC Data Source-ozssc-100</name>
    <jdbc-driver-params>
        <url>jdbc:postgresql://10.0.1.100:5433/ozssc</url>
        <driver-name>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-name>
        <properties>
            <property>
                <name>user</name>
                <value>tomcat</value>
            </property>
        </properties>
        <password-encrypted>{AES}xluimFDWO5jKhVeZAeuFt+w10T5uHYZo3CCOll3aHeM=</password-encrypted>
    </jdbc-driver-params>
    <jdbc-connection-pool-params>
        <test-table-name>SQL SELECT 1</test-table-name>
    </jdbc-connection-pool-params>
    <jdbc-data-source-params>
        <jndi-name>jdbc/postgres_ozssc_100</jndi-name>
        <global-transactions-protocol>OnePhaseCommit</global-transactions-protocol>
    </jdbc-data-source-params>
</jdbc-data-source>
```

Seems there is nothing wrong here, but every time I reboot my Macmini. suppose my weblogic will auto restart, but I found my EJB application always failed restart in my weblogic context.

When I tried to restart my EJB application, I get datasource not found in jndi exception and my  EJB application fail to restart.

When I extend my JNDI tree from my weblogic context, I always found my configured jdbc datasource always disappear, I have delete it and rebuild it from scratch. And then my EJB application will be start again.

Any idea with this situation??

Any suggestion and advice are welcome!!

Appreciated! Good weekend!

Comment: Does the datasource xml file in <domain>/config/jdbc get deleted? This is strange because the datasource created via Admin can be controlled by console, WLST, JMX or direct OS itself. Things to do 1. Undeploy EJB and check. 2. Then restart web logic alone and check. 3. Restart the Mac mini server. If only 3 is creating issue check OS level stuff.

Comment: the datasource configure file xml is here. not disappear.

Comment: What errors occur in the weblogic log file when you start the server? Does it show up in your admin console `JDBC Data Sources` link?

Comment: Not always disappear, in last 5 days, I had two days lost it, have to add it back again, seems Weblogic 12C is not very stable. And there is an other issue is very funny. In last 5 days, Weblogic 12C was restarted everyday, there are 2 days it started to listen at IPv6 and 3days listen at IPv4. i.e. if datasource JNDI lost, Weblogic listen at IPv6, if datasource is here, it listens at IPv4.

Answer (score 0):

I've got same issue with WebLogic `12.2.1.4.0` in docker: datasource dissappeared on WebLogic start (required part was inside of `config.xml` after stopping). Enabling configuration backup solved this trouble.